# Django Login Access with token

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am developing a Django project, I have created an API in the same project since other tools should be able to use functions from this project. This method is not working and I need someone who has done a similar thing to assist with a more refined and secured method or point out where am doing wrong.

When a user is registered, I create an access token ( md5 has ) for this user and store it in a model, each token has a user foreign key.

```
class AuthToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.TextField()

    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

in the API, I have added a function to authenticate the user with the token.
When the view to authenticate the user is invoked, what I do is.

1. Check if the token exists.
2. Get the user ( AuthToken.user.username )
3. Get user password ( AuthToken.user.password)
4. Authenticate these details with Django authenticate

I understand this will definitely fail since the password fetched from AuthToken.user.password with be an encrypted one, and passing the encrypted password to Django for authentication will encrypt that and compare again.

Below is my API authentication view

```
if module == 'auth': # authentication model queried
    api_token = crud # api access token
    
    token_filter = AuthToken.objects.filter(token=api_token) # filter for token existence
    
    if token_filter.count() == 1: # if there is token
        token_d = AuthToken.objects.get(token=api_token)
        username = token_d.user.username
        password = token_d.user.password

        # login
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        try:
            # check if user is valid
            if hasattr(user, 'is_active'):
                auth_login(request, user)
                # Redirect to a success page.
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request,
                               f"There is an error logging in, please check your credentials again or contact "
                               f"Administrator")
                return redirect('login')

        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f"There was an error {e}")
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        return HttpResponse('INVALID TOKEN')
```

```
elif module == 'auth': # authentication model queried
    api_token = crud # api access token
    
    token_filter = AuthToken.objects.filter(token=api_token) # filter for token existence
    
    if token_filter.count() == 1: # if there is token
        token_d = AuthToken.objects.get(token=api_token)
        username = token_d.user.username
        password = token_d.user.password

        # login
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        try:
            # check if user is valid
            if hasattr(user, 'is_active'):
                auth_login(request, user)
                # Redirect to a success page.
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request,
                               f"There is an error logging in, please check your credentials again or contact "
                               f"Administrator")
                return redirect('login')

        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f"There was an error {e}")
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        return HttpResponse('INVALID TOKEN')
```

Comment: Share entire `AuthToken` model, where is the `password` field in that?

Comment: @SunderamDubey 

The password and username should be taken from the user column in AuthToken since it is a foreign key

`class AuthToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.TextField()

    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)`

Comment: So as far as I understand it is the issue of not logging the user? Why do you maintained two separate conditions (if and elif) although they are same.

Comment: token itself is a cryptic value so why do we need to fetch user password and need to authenticate?
token_filter.count() == 1 why do we are checking by ==1. As model supports multiple token for same user?
How do you handle token expiry time?
What are you going to achieve? please kindly state those in details.

Comment: @SaifulAzad A user will strictly have one token, and will be notified when about to expire through contact medium to renew the token. when token expires it will be deleted, no user will have more than one token.

Comment: @SunderamDubey The codes are the same because stack requires I add what I have tried that's why I have added the same code as also what I have tried. Elif because the API will execute functions base on module. There is another module as condition.

Comment: Is the issue with authentication?

Comment: Is this `authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)` working perfectly in your code are you sure?

Comment: Can you please tell do you have custom user model as you specified `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `user` foreign key, can you please that model as you are not using inbuilt `User` model, I'll provide the solution.

Comment: md5 is considered insecure, consider replacement: see this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/what-is-the-recommended-replacement-for-md5)